# When to use Web Services in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I was watching a javascript tutorial and the person doing it created a simple toUpper function that he accessed through javascript, actually used javascript to call the web service. It didn't give me any explanation why he chose to do that so I want to know when is it applicable to use them and how they benefit me instead of using let's say c# classes or just writing the whole function in javascript.

Comment: That one example is a good example of when _not_ to use a web service. The same function can be performed quite well in JavaScript.

Comment: Could you give me a good example when it's good to use a web service?

Comment: When you need something not available in the client, like, data or business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web services are also great to share data between multiple applications.

For example if you have a domain and services layer you may create a server that your website, andoird/iphone app, and console application may access without duplicating your business logic.

Basically it will be for retrieving data and then let your application decide what to do with that data.

Answer (score 0):

Use web services instead of C# classes in following cases

1. You want to expose some functionality to outside
   world/consumers/other applications
2. You want to decouple parts of
   your system so that they can be changed without affecting other
   parts of application
3. You want to do make your application scaleable,
   so you create webserices and deploy those on different servers